# Would light sails be a practical means of travel in the center of Andromeda?

Tags: estimation, galaxies, propulsion, space-travel

I've read that at Andromeda's center, stars are only 0.008 lightyears apart from each other. Is this a short enough distance for light sails to be a practical means of space travel, or is this still too far to reach in any reasonable amount of time on a light sail.

I know light sails can reach up to a 10th the speed of light, but how long would that take, and how fast would they get over this sort a distance? I think those would be the most important factors.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about [space.se]

Comment: Are you referring to Earth's human civilization? Because we are not in the Andromeda Galaxy. We have to reach first the 2.5 million light years faraway galaxy from ours let alone the center of the Andromeda galaxy.  So what is the point of asking this question? Would't better to ask how long with a light sail to reach Alpha Centauri for example which is the closest solar system?

Comment: I have voted to close the question because Ben has not shown he has made any attempt to figure out the underlying issues for himself.

Comment: the is not enough starlight in between galaxies, I believe

Comment: I'm aware humans are not in Andromeda. The question is more a hypothetical of if natives of the Andromedan center would be able to use lightsailing as a practical means of interstellar travel, as their stars would be much closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is why light sails would not be practical for transport in a region with lots of stars close together.

For a sail to experience a net force arising from photon collisions, there must be more collisions happening on the back of the sail than on its front side. In a densely-packed matrix of stars, the sail would be illuminated more or less evenly in all directions which means you'd have to be close to one star in particular to develop propulsion, and the strength of that propulsive force would fall off as you sailed away from that star and toward another nearby star along your direction of travel- which would then start slowing you down by "blowing" on the wrong side of the sail.

The forces developed by a light sail are tiny, and it would still take a very long time to build up any sort of speed even on the core of Andromeda.